# Time-sensitive application in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to generate an event exactly every 1s. I'm testing setTimeout function as following:

```
   window.onload = function() {
        var oldTime = Date.now();

        setTimeout(function printTime() {
            newTime = Date.now();
            console.log(newTime - oldTime);
            oldTime = newTime;
            setTimeout(printTime, 1000);
        }, 1000);
    }
```

It returns 1s with a little bit offset:

```
testTimeout.js:6 1005
testTimeout.js:6 1006
2testTimeout.js:6 1001
testTimeout.js:6 1006
testTimeout.js:6 1005
testTimeout.js:6 1006
testTimeout.js:6 1005
```

Where does the offset come from? Is it because of the oldTime and newTime calculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to generate an event exactly every 1s.

There is no way to do this with exact precision.

The time passed to `setTimeout` is the **minimum guaranteed time** in which your code will run, not the exact time.

The time represents in how many milliseconds the JS Engine will push that function to the [Event Queue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop). Once the function is in the Event Queue, it **runs after all the current tasks present in the queue**, such as events and other timers, which will create a delay.

Additionally, no task can be executed from the Event Queue while any regular JS code is running which could also potentially create small delays.

For example, this function `test`:

```js
setTimeout(function test() {
  console.log('second');
}, 0);
for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++); // the number 1000000 is an arbitrary big number
console.log('first');
```

Will run after the loop below it has finished, which will be more than `0` milliseconds away.

In fact, if that loop was infinite, the `setTimeout` callback will never fire.

---

*Note*: As mentioned by **nnnnnn** in the comments, the actual minimum time, as [per the HTML5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#timers), in which `setTimeout` will push a function to the Event Queue is 4ms, regardless if we put less. Previously that limit used to be 10ms.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Minimum_delay_and_timeout_nesting)

> In fact, 4 ms is specified by the HTML5 spec and is consistent across browsers released in 2010 and onward. Prior to (Firefox 5.0 / Thunderbird 5.0 / SeaMonkey 2.2), the minimum timeout value for nested timeouts was 10 ms.

Comment: In other words, you *can't* schedule a function to run at an *exact* time. (Also, regarding the 0ms timeout, even without a long-running loop after it it will still be a minimum of 4ms before it runs because browsers round smaller delays up to 4ms - though your point about other code having to finish first still stands.)